# Apache Rewrites not working due to Akamai

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a website which is setup with akamai. My domain and subdomains are mapped onto an Akamai IP.

I have written an Apache rewrite which does an internal URL X to another internal URL Y. This rewrite works fine as long as I am testing in my local setup or for those subdomains which are not mapped onto Akamai but directly onto my Public IP.

My suspicion is that while rewriting the request apache is not able to resolve the IP of the app server correctly.

When I add entries to my /etc/hosts file pointing the domain/subdomain to my internal IP the rewrites work.

Now, I have a huge list of subdomains and it can grow as well. Is there another way to fix this problem without having to make entries in the /etc/hosts file ?

I would much appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: What kind of a rewrite are you doing exactly, can you show an example?

Comment: This question should be asked on server fault

Comment: Here is the rewrite rule which I have..RewriteRule ^/(context)/(sub-context)(-)([-a-z0-9A-Z]*)/(.*)$ /$1/$2/$5 [P,L]

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use a different DNS server, or re-write the URL to use a hostname which works correctly.

However the net effect is the same as changing the entry in your hosts file. But if you are not sending back a redirect from the rewrite, then you'll get marginally better performance by using the loopback adapter rather than (the address of a) real NIC. So just put it in you hosts file as 127.0.0.1 but more importantly this address should never change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually quite surprised to hear that the rewrite rule you say you have:

```
RewriteRule ^/(context)/(sub-context)(-)([-a-z0-9A-Z]*)/(.*)$ /$1/$2/$5 [P,L]
```

works *at all*, since [according to the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) it shouldn't:

> "`^/somepath(.*) /otherpath$1 [P]`     doesn't make sense, not supported"

If you *want* to use the [`[P]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p), your rewrite target should be a full URL.  However, I very much suspect that the `[P]` flag is, in fact, *not* what you want, and that removing it might fix the problem.